# convert war file to exe file

Tags: jar, exe, archive, file-conversion, war

I have a file in `.war` format.
Is it possible to convert it to an `.exe` or `.jar` file?

Comment: a war file is just a plain zip file, so you can do the same kind of things as a zip file

Comment: maybe this helpful: https://github.com/jfrichard/executable-war

Comment: @RageZ: but how can i convert that type of file to exe file? is there any converter for it? for jar to exe i already find the converter.
@Thilo: this example need to use maven but i'm using tomcat.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all ***why you need to do such thing?***

As stated on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_file_format_%28Sun%29) :

> A war file is a JAR file used to
>   distribute a collection of JavaServer
>   Pages, servlets, Java classes, XML
>   files, tag libraries and static Web
>   pages (HTML and related files) that
>   together constitute a Web application.

A war file is you application which is ready to run on server. As you said you are using tomcat you just need to put the war file in webapps folder of tomcat. And start the tomcat server. Its done. Your project will successfully run. No need to build exe [of war] for this.

If you wanna give client a setup that will look like set up and setups all things to run your app then you can use a exe maker software (like [installJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/))and make your exe such that it includes tomcat with your war in webapps. Make shortcut to startup file of tomcat. So now when user clicks on shortcut tomcat will start and with it your application will also start and user can access it on browser.

Answer (score 2):

Both war and jar are ZIPs. Thus, they can be **easily converted**.

However, wars usually store **webs**, while jars contain **desktop programs**.
So, converting a *war* to a *jar* **would not be useful** because, as the *war* contained a web, **the converted *jar* will also contain a web**, so trying to run it (as a program) will cause an error.

If you're looking to convert a web (the *war*) into a desktop app, this is **not** the way.
Please, take a look at [Prism](http://prism.mozillalabs.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What i'm trying to do is register .war program to task scheduler so that it can run automatically based on my expectation. As I know, that program should be in .exe to run in task scheduler. That's why im trying to convert that .war to .exe.

Comment: Thanks for the details. When you say "run the `.war` program", what do you exactly mean? Consult a page or a Servlet on the `.war`, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

.war files are intended to be run inside a web container. So what you might want to do it to put the .war file in one, and run the web container from the task scheduler. I've done something like this before (although not with a task scheduler) using [Jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/). Jetty itself is a java program, so you just start it by running `java.exe -jar start.jar` in the Jetty directory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can covert a war into a jar file by just changing the suffix.

Both wars and jars have the same basic format (they're ZIP files), but wars usually have dependent jars and a web.xml file that describes the application.

Jars and Wars contain Java class files and need a Java engine to run. However, I suspect there are tools out there that can package a JRE, with a lightweight server (if one is needed) and the war/jar file into a single "exe" file for Windows.

I just Googled [java Windows exe wrappers](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=java+windows+exe+wrappers&aq=f&aqi=g-v1g-b1&aql=&oq=) and found the top four results looking pretty much like what you're after.