# What is the correct naming convention for MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java, manifest, war

How do I set an entry point to my generated war file?
Here is my Manifest file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Test
```

with Package name:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.process.Test
```

When I deploy it and try to run it from cmd using : java -jar myFile.war

I get :

```
NoClassDefFoundError: Test
```

regardless of whether I specify a package name with the main class.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The package name is required. Are you working with a jar or a war?

Comment: You can't run it that way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591787/convert-war-file-to-exe-file

Answer (score 0):

Does your class have no package?
Try specyfing it as:

```
Main-Class: com.maventest.Test
```

Comment: yes it does have a package? I 've tried with : com.process.Test and it still gives the same error.

Comment: And is it war or jar? War is for web applications, while jar is for general java programs/libraries. And how do you build your jar? With maven?