# How to convert a .war file into a JAR file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exe, war

I did a project based on J2EE framework. Using spring/ hibernate technologies. And used Tomcat as my servlet container. I want to create a JAR file and make my web project executable. This question is asked before but answers are ambiguous.

Comment: It is impossible. Diferent platform have diferent formats for executables.

Comment: I've read a couple of related questions and they all say basically the same: package your application with your choice of servlet runner (Tomcat, Jetty, ...), so I don't know why you say these answers are ambiguous?

Comment: You can create a maven project with tomcat7 plugin: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/executable-war-jar.html

Comment: you could convert the project to Spring Boot application and create an executable Jar file which would be portable I believe.

Comment: You can easily deploy a `.war` file in tomcat server. Why do you need a `.exe` file?

Comment: Can you explain how to make an exe file regarding this?

Comment: I don't believe you can create an exe, youll create an executable JAR file

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591787/convert-war-file-to-exe-file)

Comment: okay I'll edit the question to JAR. Thanks

Comment: Once you have a JAR, you could use Launch4J to create a Windows Executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Spring Boot, this will help you create a jar that can be started with

```
java -jar <your-jar-file>
```

It would not need to get deployed into a servlet container, instead it will run with an embedded tomcat. You'd need to install a java runtime wherever you want to run it, though.

See [this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

To convert war file to jar in the spring boot, you need to do 3 steps.

1. convert war to jar in the pom.xml

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

2. extends SpringBootServletInitializer
3. override configure

```
public class Your_Application_Name extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder springApplicationBuilder){
        return springApplicationBuilder.sources(Your_Application_Name.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Your_Application_Name.class, args);
    }
```